# datagrid adding sorting function to a non data column

Tags: qcubed

I have 4 columns in a datagrid. The manuals give examples on how to sort on a column derived from the database using the `array('OrderByClause' => QQ::OrderBy(QQN::Pubs()->Name)`

however, **I want to sort on a calculated results** `$_FORM->getDistance($_ITEM)`

What I have so far is this:

> $this->dtgPersons->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Row Number', 'CurrentRowIndex + 1) ?>'));
>
> $this->dtgPersons->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Pub Name', 'Name ?>', 'Width=200',     //));
>           array('OrderByClause' => QQ::OrderBy(QQN::Pubs()->Name), 'ReverseOrderByClause' => QQ::OrderBy(QQN::Pubs()->Name, false))));
>
> $this->dtgPersons->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Street', 'Address1 ?>', 'Width=200',
>            array('OrderByClause' => QQ::OrderBy(QQN::Pubs()->Address1), 'ReverseOrderByClause' => QQ::OrderBy(QQN::Pubs()->Address1,
>   false))));
>
> $this->dtgPersons->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Distance from
>   Location', 'getDistance($_ITEM) ?>', 'Width=300'));

This following line works on columns that have a sort on them

> $this->dtgPersons->SortColumnIndex = 2;

Comment: I am not sure this is possible, the sorting is based on SQL statements. I will look into this and answer if I can.

Comment: Hi @Scottux I wondered if you did get anywhere with sorting on the output of the function getDistance() and not the database as it is fundamental to my application

Comment: I have so far been unsuccessful and I haven't tried again lately. Vaibhav's suggestion is probably the best idea, one of those guys may have done this already.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about this. Try asking at the github page - http://github.com/qcubed/framework.